# Merging a local branch with the master - resolving conflicts

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to merge a local branch with the master and there were some conflicts. I resolved the conflicts, however, I cannot commit the changes. The error that I get is - `fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.`

How can I check existing conflicts and resolve them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after which command do you get that error? Normally you get a merge conflict, you resolve it, do `git add` of your resulotions and then something like `git merge --continue`

Comment: Did you check the documentation? for example [mergetool](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool) and [basic merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Answer (score 1):

You can write `git status` to reveal what files that need's to be changed. Be sure to correct and add those files to your commit.

You can also check out some guides for how to merge correctly as mentioned above on these links:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
And the mergetool:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool